# How do you retrieve the provisioning token for a Edge Module using Azure Video Indexer?

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

Recently Azure Video Analyzer became Azure Video Indexer. I'm trying to connect a camera to the Video Indexer using a Edge Modul in the IoT Hub. Part of the template which was designed for the Video Analyzer needs a "AVA_PROVISIONING_TOKEN". I can find the api call to retrieve this when using Azure Video Analyzer:

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Media/videoAnalyzers/{accountName}/edgeModules/{edgeModuleName}/listProvisioningToken?api-version=2021-11-01-preview
```

But since this service is not continued I'm not receiving any data. I tried changing it to providers/Microsoft.VideoIndexer but this is not supported by the api.

The only other thing that comes close is this call:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.VideoIndexer/accounts?api-version=2022-04-13-preview
```

But this only retrieves the provisioning state not the actual Token.

If anybody knows a workaround either with the api or the azure portal I would be very thankful.

Sources:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/videoindexer/accounts/list

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ai-applied-ai-blog/build-intelligent-video-solutions-with-axis-cameras-and-azure/ba-p/2967607

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/azure-video-analyzer/video-analyzer-docs/edge/deploy-iot-edge-device

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it was "Azure Video Analyzer for Media" that became Azure Video Indexer. This is a cloud-only PaaS product.

You mention trying to connect a camera using an Edge Module in the IoT Hub. This edge module was part of "Azure Video Analyzer", the retirement of which was [announced](https://aka.ms/avaretirement) in April. This module should no longer be used.

Comment: Exactly, basically I'm doing something similar to this: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ai-applied-ai-blog/build-intelligent-video-solutions-with-axis-cameras-and-azure/ba-p/2967607 
Thank you for telling me about the Edge Module, I thought that was still good to go since it still shows up in the IoT Hub ressource and I can still set up a device like that.